# How do I match a params in React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have been trying to display the product name in the `ProductScreen` component by passing the ID of the image.

My router configuration looks like this:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route>
      <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
      <Route path='/cart' element={<ProductScreen />} />
      <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} />
    </Route>
  )
)
```

The `id` is then used to retrieve the product name from product.js
This is to be displayed inside the productscreen.js

```
import products from '../products'

function ProductScreen({match}) {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id == match.params.id)
  return (
    <div>
      {product.name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why? You're in a browser, why make React-Router reinvent the wheel when you can already trivially check for this with `new URLSearchParams(location.search)` in any code that needs to look at URL query arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-router-dom@6` removed route props, use the `useParams` hook in the routed component.

Be aware also that `Array.prototype.find` ***does*** return undefined if/when no element in the array is matched. The UI could should check first that a result was found.

The route path parameters are ***always*** a string type, so you will also want to use a type-safe comparison to your data. I suggest converting and using string comparisons and use a strict equality check.

Example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import products from '../products';

function ProductScreen() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const product = products.find((p) => String(p._id) === id);

  if (!product) {
    return <div>No product.</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {product.name}
    </div>
  );
}
```